# How to show info about DVB (Digital Video Broadcast) cards in the system

Tags: linux, dvb, tuner

Which Bash commands are beneficial to display the information about all [DVB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVB-S) cards (dvb-t, dvb-s, ...)  connected the system (via any port:  usb, pci, ...)?

My needed info is:  name, type, frequency, number of tuners per card.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mumudvb -l`

Or use `lsdvb`

`lsdvb` have a problem that if the tuner in using with another application, it can not return information about tuner but `mumudvb -l` work full.